# Excel formula to get most common values amongst 3 cells?

Tags: excel, compare

These are requirements:

- If there is no common value then I just want it to choose the first
- If that cell is empty, I just want it to choose a cell with a value

For example:

```
                 Output
  1     2    3        4
⎜Cat ⎜Cat ⎜Dog ⎜    Cat
⎜Dog ⎜Cat ⎜Cat ⎜    Cat
⎜Dog ⎜Dog ⎜Dog ⎜    Dog
⎜Cat ⎜Pig ⎜Dog ⎜    Cat
⎜    ⎜Dog ⎜    ⎜    Dog
```

Comment: I slightly improved wording/formatting of your question. But then: it is always better if you try things yourself first. Don't just dump requirements, hoping that other people do all the work for you. Try it, and when you have code that doesn't work, put up a question with that code to get help fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - note that it is an `ARRAY` formula, so must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:C1,MODE(MATCH(A1:C1,A1:C1,0))),INDEX(A1:C1,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(A1:C1),0)))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response! Yes it works only if there is 2 or more common. But if there isn't any common i just want any result of the 3 columns preferably the first.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ipZIXWB.png It looks like you haven't entered your formulas as `ARRAY` formulas.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use COUNTIF entered as an array formula

```
=INDEX(A1:C1,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A1:C1,A1:C1)),COUNTIF(A1:C1,A1:C1),0))
```